# Xcode 6.0.1 crashes when merging 2 branches

Tags: ios, xcode, git, merge, branch

Every time I try to merge a branch into another branch Xcode 6.0.1 crashes.

So far I have:

1. Tried from a different computer to merge the same branches (pushed them and pulled them before obviously) and it still crashes.
2. Created a new branch from the "faulty branch" added a space in it and merged it back into the "faulty branch" with success. but couldn't merge it into the original branch i wanted to.

Whats wrong with Xcode ? How can I merge the branches ? (there are about 100 files to merge)

**EDIT 2**

1. One of the files has a conflict, after resolving the conflict in the Xcode merge editor, it will crash not only when trying to merge but even when trying to look at on of the other files (looking at other files doesn't crash before resolving the conflict).
2. editing one of the branches in such a way to avoid the conflict upon merging will save resolving the conflict, but Xcode will still crash when hitting merge

**EDIT** - adding the crash alert :

```
    Process:         Xcode [3146]
    Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
    Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
    Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
    Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
    App Item ID:     497799835
    App External ID: 712682811
    Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:  launchd [162]
    Responsible:     Xcode [3146]
    User ID:         501

    Date/Time:       2014-09-30 15:30:49.320 +0300
    OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
    Report Version:  11
    Anonymous UUID:  3A19C91F-0A10-76C9-10BB-C3B0EABB5390


    Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

    Application Specific Information:
    Sending merge: to <IDESourceControlMergeWindowController: 0x7fc4d0974a90> from         <NSButton: 0x7fc4cd57e7e0>
    ProductBuildVersion: 6A317
    ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEPlugins/IDEPlugins-                6244/IDEQuickLookEditor/Comparison/IDEQuickLookVersionsTwoUpSubmode.m:210
    Details:  primaryDocumentLocation should be an instance inheriting from         IDESourceControlDocumentLocation, but it is nil
    Object:   <IDEQuickLookVersionsTwoUpSubmode: 0x7fc4d0e515d0>
    Method:   -_saveMergeState
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc4c9716f00>{name = (null), num = 1}
    Hints:   
      0: Sending merge: to <IDESourceControlMergeWindowController: 0x7fc4d0974a90> from         <NSButton: 0x7fc4cd57e7e0>
    Backtrace:
      0  0x0000000106343f0a -[IDEAssertionHandler         handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:]         (in IDEKit)
      1  0x0000000105106baf _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      2  0x0000000105106e9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      3  0x00000001150b4cee -[IDEQuickLookVersionsTwoUpSubmode _saveMergeState] (in         IDEQuickLookEditor)
      4  0x00000001065f69f4 -[IDESourceControlConflictResolutionController         completeConflictResolution] (in IDEKit)
      5  0x000000010646d4f4 -[IDESourceControlMergeWindowController merge:] (in IDEKit)
      6  0x00007fff85a2b260 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
      7  0x000000010566d200 __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in         DVTKit)
      8  0x0000000105107ec2 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
      9  0x000000010553777e -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
     10  0x00007fff85a2b0de -[NSControl sendAction:to:] (in AppKit)
     11  0x00007fff85a77c4d -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] (in AppKit)
     12  0x00007fff85a91655 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
     13  0x00007fff85a90a27 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
     14  0x00007fff85a9013d -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
     15  0x00007fff85a11a58 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
     16  0x00007fff859b05d4 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
     17  0x000000010610fc74 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
     18  0x00007fff858009f9 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
     19  0x00007fff857eb783 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
     20  0x00007fff8e89d5fd start (in libdyld.dylib)

    Performing @selector(merge:) from sender NSButton 0x7fc4cd57e7e0
    abort() called

    Application Specific Signatures:
    (primaryDocumentLocation) != nil
```

Comment: Usually when it crashes there is an alert, and if you dig down you can find the actual error message and dump. Please post it!

Comment: I always had a problem with that, thats why I use the terminal for git. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: @PeterDeWeese, any clue what is happening here?

Comment: No idea, but now people will be able to look up the issue more easily!

Comment: ugh...someone please shed some light on this! on latest xcode and latest os x and it crashes on every merge, regardless of any conflicts or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue.

Try to update the OS X to its latest version (10.9.5) and see if its solves the problem.

Comment: Git merge crashed on me on 10.9.5 too. It seems like a bad streak - 6.0.1 felt like an improvement over 6.0 in Gif defect fixes, but not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue here and is quite unnerving!
The way I solved it is to use git merge from command line and use whatever diff tools you have, I just used the opendiff standard one.
I know is not ideal but at least you can get going ......