# Xcode 6.3.1 crashes when merging two branches. Solutions?

Tags: git, crash, xcode6, crash-reports

Issue seems similar to: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120846/xcode-6-0-1-crashes-when-merging-2-branches), but the App specific message seems a bit different.  Hoping someone will say: (Insert simple procedure) and you can fix your problem!  Unlikely, so posting this mostly for putting this issue out there.

Here is the first part of the Crash report generated (whole one is *really* long):

```
Process:               Xcode [693]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.1 (7703)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7703000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812230896
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [693]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-04-24 09:17:20.460 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        A069458D-BAB6-76AB-047A-F3E94B6484C3


Time Awake Since Boot: 450 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D1002
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-7703/DVTFoundation/Protocols/DVTInvalidation.m:216
Details:  Message sent to invalidated object: <IDEKeyDrivenNavigableItem_AnyDVTLandmarkItemSwift, 0x7fb299f60830>.

Backtrace for invalidation:
   0  0x0000000107fd4015 -[DVTInvalidationMixIn invalidate] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x00000001091d475f -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator forgetItems:] (in IDEKit)
  2  0x00000001091e331b -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator forgetNavigableItems:] (in IDEKit)
  3  0x0000000109264eca -[IDENavigableItem _updateMutableChildItems:forChangeKind:atIndexes:] (in IDEKit)
  4  0x00000001092649b8 -[IDENavigableItem updateChildItemsForChangeKind:atIndexes:] (in IDEKit)
  5  0x00000001094351a1 __46-[IDEFileNavigableItem _updateEditorDocument:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
  6  0x00000001080f7a9b __73-[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke183 (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x000000010806f55c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x0000000107f208ac -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
  9  0x00007fff97d8b0f3 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
 10  0x00007fff97d97d68 NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff97d5097d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] (in Foundation)
 12  0x000000011293e12f -[IDESourceCodeDocument textStorageDidUpdateSourceLandmarks:] (in IDESourceEditor)
 13  0x00000001085ab416 -[DVTTextStorage _invalidateSourceLandmarks:] (in DVTKit)
 14  0x0000000108574a61 -[DVTTextStorage topSourceLandmark] (in DVTKit)
 15  0x0000000108589f04 -[DVTTextStorage sourceLandmarkAtCharacterIndex:] (in DVTKit)
 16  0x000000011299e288 -[IDESourceCodeEditor _currentSelectedLandmarkItem] (in IDESourceEditor)
 17  0x000000011299e0ff -[IDESourceCodeEditor _refreshCurrentSelectedItemsIfNeeded] (in IDESourceEditor)
 18  0x000000011293d7fa -[IDESourceCodeEditor currentSelectedItems] (in IDESourceEditor)
 19  0x0000000109346542 __52-[IDEEditorContext _updateSubDocumentNavigableItems]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 20  0x000000010919751a -[IDEEditorContext _performBlockInsideReentrantGuard:] (in IDEKit)
 21  0x00000001091f2bf8 -[IDEEditorContext _updateSubDocumentNavigableItems] (in IDEKit)
 22  0x00000001091f96e6 -[IDEEditorContext _greatestDocumentAncestorWasForgotten] (in IDEKit)
 23  0x000000010933e546 __43-[IDEEditorContext initWithNibName:bundle:]_block_invoke144 (in IDEKit)
 24  0x00000001080c3574 -[_DVTNotificationReceiver receiveNotification:] (in DVTFoundation)
 25  0x00007fff959bd45c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x00007fff958ad634 _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 27  0x00007fff97d509d1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
 28  0x00000001080c4118 -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in DVTFoundation)
 29  0x00000001094762ba -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator _postWillForgetNotification:] (in IDEKit)
 30  0x00000001091d4694 -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator forgetItems:] (in IDEKit)
 31  0x00000001091e331b -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator forgetNavigableItems:] (in IDEKit)
 32  0x0000000109264eca -[IDENavigableItem _updateMutableChildItems:forChangeKind:atIndexes:] (in IDEKit)
 33  0x00000001092649b8 -[IDENavigableItem updateChildItemsForChangeKind:atIndexes:] (in IDEKit)
 34  0x000000010923471c -[IDEContainerFileReferenceNavigableItem updateChildRepresentedObjects] (in IDEKit)
 35  0x00000001091cdc7a -[_IDEContainerItemNavigableItemExtraInfo processModelObjectGraphNotification:] (in IDEKit)
 36  0x00007fff97d842cc -[__NSObserver _doit:] (in Foundation)
 37  0x00007fff959bd45c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
 38  0x00007fff958ad634 _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 39  0x00007fff97d509d1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
 40  0x00000001080c4118 -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in DVTFoundation)
 41  0x0000000107f6396b -[DVTModelObjectGraph _coalescingTick] (in DVTFoundation)
 42  0x0000000108053fe3 __58-[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 43  0x00000001080d687a -[DVTModelGraphTransactionScope performTransaction:] (in DVTFoundation)
 44  0x0000000108053ed9 -[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:] (in DVTFoundation)
 45  0x0000000108d4bffa +[IDEContainer _invalidateContainer:] (in IDEFoundation)
 46  0x0000000108aeb86b -[IDEContainer _respondToFileChangeOnDiskWithFilePath:] (in IDEFoundation)
 47  0x0000000108aeaea3 -[IDEContainer _filePathDidChangeWithPendingChangeDictionary] (in IDEFoundation)
 48  0x00007fff97d9441b __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)
 49  0x00007fff959542e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 50  0x00007fff95953f73 __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 51  0x00007fff959c753d __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
 52  0x00007fff9590f608 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 53  0x00007fff9590ebd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 54  0x00007fff8cc3556f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 55  0x00007fff8cc352ea ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 56  0x00007fff8cc3512b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 57  0x00007fff970209bb _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 58  0x00007fff9701ff68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 59  0x0000000108668dda -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 60  0x00007fff97015bf3 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 61  0x00007fff96f92354 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 62  0x00007fff95d5e5c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 63  0x0000000000000001

Function: void DVTInvalidationCoreInvalidateInline(NSObject<DVTInvalidation> *__strong)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb291616e20>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001093890a2 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001080e4c2b _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001080e4e8e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000107fd41d7 -[DVTInvalidationMixIn invalidate] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x00000001091d475f -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator forgetItems:] (in IDEKit)
  5  0x00000001091e331b -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator forgetNavigableItems:] (in IDEKit)
  6  0x0000000109264eca -[IDENavigableItem _updateMutableChildItems:forChangeKind:atIndexes:] (in IDEKit)
  7  0x00000001092649b8 -[IDENavigableItem updateChildItemsForChangeKind:atIndexes:] (in IDEKit)
  8  0x000000010923471c -[IDEContainerFileReferenceNavigableItem updateChildRepresentedObjects] (in IDEKit)
  9  0x00000001091cdc7a -[_IDEContainerItemNavigableItemExtraInfo processModelObjectGraphNotification:] (in IDEKit)
 10  0x00007fff97d842cc -[__NSObserver _doit:] (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff959bd45c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
 12  0x00007fff958ad634 _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 13  0x00007fff97d509d1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
 14  0x00000001080c4118 -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in DVTFoundation)
 15  0x0000000107f6396b -[DVTModelObjectGraph _coalescingTick] (in DVTFoundation)
 16  0x0000000108053fe3 __58-[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 17  0x00000001080d687a -[DVTModelGraphTransactionScope performTransaction:] (in DVTFoundation)
 18  0x0000000108053ed9 -[DVTModelObjectGraph performBlockCoalescingModelChanges:] (in DVTFoundation)
 19  0x0000000108d4bffa +[IDEContainer _invalidateContainer:] (in IDEFoundation)
 20  0x0000000108aeb86b -[IDEContainer _respondToFileChangeOnDiskWithFilePath:] (in IDEFoundation)
 21  0x0000000108aeaea3 -[IDEContainer _filePathDidChangeWithPendingChangeDictionary] (in IDEFoundation)
 22  0x00007fff97d9441b __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)
 23  0x00007fff959542e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 24  0x00007fff95953f73 __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 25  0x00007fff959c753d __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x00007fff9590f608 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 27  0x00007fff9590ebd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 28  0x00007fff8cc3556f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 29  0x00007fff8cc352ea ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 30  0x00007fff8cc3512b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 31  0x00007fff970209bb _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 32  0x00007fff9701ff68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 33  0x0000000108668dda -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 34  0x00007fff97015bf3 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 35  0x00007fff96f92354 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 36  0x00007fff95d5e5c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 37  0x0000000000000001

abort() called
```